# Ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите почему я не могу вывести переменную a?

```
xmlh=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlh.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlh.readyState==4 && xmlh.status==200) {
        alert(a);
    }
}
xmlh.open('GET','first.php?a=22',true);

xmlh.send();
```

как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlh.onreadystatechange = function ( data ) {
    if ( xmlh.readyState == 4 && xmlh.status == 200 ) {
        alert( data );
    }
}
```